# HttpClient response is null when using proxy (Charles)

Tags: android, proxy, httpclient

I have some rest services returning JSON that are working just fine.  BUT when I make the emulator run through a web proxy (Charles) then all of the sudden I'm getting null for the getResponse().

Whats frustrating is that I can see in Charles that the response and request look great.

- Anyone else seen problems with org.apache.http.client.HttpClient when the emulator is running through a proxy?
- Suggestions on how to get around this?
- Should I switch to another proxy? I know of fiddler but that is pc only...
- Any other ideas?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't know why the response is coming back null, but I was able to view the traffic with an HTTP sniffer NOT a proxy.  I used HTTPScoop, which is a nice little app.

Also the nice thing about using HTTPScoop is that I can also see traffic on my actual device when I turn on internet sharing and have my phone use the wifi from my mac. So this is a good deal for debugging what happens on the phone itself.

Answer (score 0):

Charles works with sdk r13 and the following emulator arguments:

-http-proxy localhost.:8888 -port 5554 -debug-proxy

this was confirmed working on my mac.

Comment: ended up creating a blog post about this: http://qtcstation.com/2011/09/configuring-charles-web-debugger-to-work-with-android-devices-and-emulator/